# JSF Faces Bridge get java.lang.NullPointerException when deploying to oc4j container

Tags: oracle, jsf, portlet, oracle-adf

I am running JDeveloper 10.1.3.4 with the webcenter pre-configured oc4j.
I'm trying to portletize a vanilla JSF webcenter project.

1. I create a application using the webcenter application template.
2. Add a JSF JSP, simple called it index with all the default values.
3. Add a deployment profile and deploy to local oc4j
4. navigate to the jsf page and everything works.
5. right click on ViewController and add the library Portlet Faces Bridge
6. right click on ViewController and add a Portlet Deployment descriptor.
7. Edit portlet.xml with the values from [link text](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12524_01/webcenter.1013/e12434/jpsdg_java_adv.htm#BABBFDHA)
8. in portlet.xml i replace the Default page view with my /index.jspx

   when i try to deploy to local oc4j i get the follow

> ----  Deployment started.  ----    May 1, 2009 2:29:37 PM Target platform is
>   Standalone OC4J 10g 10.1.3
>   (localAppServer). Wrote WAR file to
>   C:\jdevstudio10134\jdev\mywork\test\ViewController\deploy\webapp2.war
>   Wrote EAR file to
>   C:\jdevstudio10134\jdev\mywork\test\ViewController\deploy\webapp2.ear
>   Backing up generic archive file
>   :/C:/jdevstudio10134/jdev/mywork/test/ViewController/deploy/webapp2_generic.ear
>   Creating WSDLs for the WSRP
>   Application WSDLs for the WSRP
>   Application have been created
>   Uploading file webapp2.ear ...
>   Uploading file webapp2.ear ...
>   Application Deployer for webapp2
>   STARTS. Copy the archive to
>   C:\jdevstudio10134\j2ee\home\applications\webapp2.ear
>   Initialize
>   C:\jdevstudio10134\j2ee\home\applications\webapp2.ear
>   begins... Unpacking webapp2.ear Done
>   unpacking webapp2.ear Unpacking
>   webapp2.war Done unpacking webapp2.war
>   Initialize
>   C:\jdevstudio10134\j2ee\home\applications\webapp2.ear
>   ends... Starting application : webapp2
>   Initializing ClassLoader(s)
>   application : webapp2 is in failed
>   state Operation failed with error:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Deployment failed Elapsed time for
>   deployment:  3 seconds
>
> Deployment incomplete.  ####    May 1, 2009 2:29:40 PM

if i deploy the WAR file by hand and navigate to the page i get 500 internal server error.

> 09/05/01 14:49:21.984 webapp2: Servlet
>   error java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:346)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:152)
>       at oracle.portlet.server.bridges.jsf.PortletViewHandlerImpl.renderView(PortletViewHandlerImpl.java:73)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:268)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:137)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:214)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0)
>   ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher
>       .java:713)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0)
>   ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher
>       .java:370)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0)
>   ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler
>       .java:871)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0)
>   ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler
>       .java:453)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0)
>   ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler
>       .java:221)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0)
>   ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:122)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0)
>   ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:111)
>       at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
>       at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0)
>   ].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor
>       .java:303)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

My portlet.xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<portlet-app version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_1_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_1_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_1_0.xsd">
 <portlet> 
     <description>myapp</description> 
     <portlet-name>test</portlet-name> 
     <display-name>myapp</display-name> 
     <portlet-class>oracle.portlet.server.bridges.jsf.FacesPortlet 
     </portlet-class> 
     <init-param> 
      <name>DefaultPage.view</name>
      <value>/index.jspx</value>
     </init-param> 
     <init-param> 
      <name>BridgeLifecycleListeners</name>
      <value>
       oracle.portlet.server.bridges.jsf.adf.ADFFacesBridgeLifecycleListener,
       oracle.portlet.server.bridges.jsf.adf.BindingFacesBridgeLifecycleListener
      </value>
     </init-param> 
    <supports> 
     <mime-type>text/html</mime-type> 
     <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode> 
     </supports> 
     <supported-locale>en</supported-locale> 
     <portlet-info> 
      <title>myapp</title> 
      <short-title>test</short-title> 
     </portlet-info> 
   </portlet> 
</portlet-app>
```

...if i delete the file and redeploy the jspx page works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should move to jdev 11g which uses wls which is much better than oc4j